# How to disable cd burning on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu

Is there any way to disable cd burning for users on ubuntu 14.04? I don't want to disable access to CD/DVD Rom. I've tried the commands below, and a user accout that was not assigned to the cdburn group but that did not prevent the burn from occurring:

```
chown root:cdburn /usr/bin/cdrecord

chmod 770 /usr/bin/cdrecord
```

The idea is to give some users the ability to burn but not others. Installing a DVD-ROM is not really what I want to do but appears to be my only option so far.

Answer (score 1):

One method of doing this (granted I'm not on Ubuntu, but I'd think it would work the same as it does on my CentOS install) is to disable that particular piece of hardware. For example:

```
[user@host bin]$ lshal |grep cd
scsi.type = 'cdrom'  (string)
info.capabilities = {'storage', 'block', 'storage.cdrom'} (string list)
storage.cdrom.bd = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.bdr = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.bdre = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.cdr = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.cdrw = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.dvd = true  (bool)
storage.cdrom.dvdplusr = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.dvdplusrdl = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.dvdplusrw = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.dvdplusrwdl = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.dvdr = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.dvdram = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.dvdrdl = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.dvdrw = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.hddvd = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.hddvdr = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.hddvdrw = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.mo = false  (bool)
storage.cdrom.mrw = true  (bool)
storage.cdrom.mrw_w = true  (bool)
storage.cdrom.read_speed = 8467  (0x2113)  (int)
storage.cdrom.support_media_changed = true  (bool)  
storage.cdrom.support_multisession = true  (bool)
storage.cdrom.write_speed = 0  (0x0)  (int)
storage.cdrom.write_speeds = {} (string list)
storage.drive_type = 'cdrom'  (string)
```

You should be able to interact with this information using the `hal-device` binary, turning off particular things like <s>`storage.cdrom.cdr = true`</s> `storage.cdrom.cd = true` which in theory should tell the system that it's a CDRom, (not a writable/re-writable device).

Although it's for Arch Linux, the methods used in [this link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=60986) should be the same or similar for other Linux distributions.

Granted I have not tested any of this, as I'm not in a position at the moment to do so, but it's something that could be experimented with relatively easy.

**Edit:**
If you go this route and start changing your HAL, I'd strongly recommend outputting copies of `lshal` and `hal-device` off to a file so you can put things back the way they were when you started, otherwise you may lose a device if any mistakes are made. (And use this information at your own risk! Messing around with your devices can be dangerous.)

Another solution, replace the drive with a CDRom drive, so you don't have to worry about anyone writing to a CD. You could probably find them relatively cheap nowadays.

**Edit 2:**
Recalled that "CDR" means "Recordable CD"... I meant "CD" which just means CDRom. The sentence has been updated above.

Comment: Ill give this a try

Comment: lshal and hal-device don't seem to be native commands in ubuntu.

Comment: Interesting... well for what it's worth I'll leave the answer there in case anyone with rpm-based distros have a similar issue. My apologies!